Estimate the maximum of scalar curvature under the Ricci flow on compact surface
Assume $M$ is compact surface, $g(t)$ satisfies the normalized Ricci flow. $R$ is the scalar curvature of $g(t)$, and $R$ is continuous. $\mu$ is the area element of $g(t)$.
Under the Ricci flow, there are
$$
\int R^2 d\mu\le Ce^{-ct} ~~~~  \tag{1}
$$
$$
\int |DR|^2 d\mu \le Ce^{-ct}   \tag{2}
$$
$$
\int |D^2R|^2 d\mu \le Ce^{-ct}   \tag{3}
$$
and $\frac{\int R d\mu}{\int d\mu}=0$. Then, how to estimate the maximum of $R$ ?
I think the key point is uniform Sobolev inequality. But I google it, there is not helpful information. Besides,  I can barely use the Sobolev inequality  (My PDE is very weak). And I fail to find helpful information in its Wiki.
PS(2024-8-29):  I find the follow theorem

$\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ is bounded, then
$$
W^{k,p}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow C^\alpha (\overline \Omega)
$$
for $p\ge 1, 0<\alpha\le 1-\frac{n}{kp},  kp >n$.

The norm of $C^\alpha$ is
$$
|u|_\alpha=|u|_0+[u]_\alpha
$$
where $|u|_0 =\sup |u(x)|$ and $[u]_\alpha =\sup \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}$.
If the theorem is right for compact manifold, then, from (3), we know $R\in W^{2,2}(M)$. Therefore, $R\in C^\alpha(M)$ for $0<\alpha\le 1/2$.  So, there is estimate
$$
|R|\le Ce^{-ct/2}
$$
Is the above process correct? Besides, is the boldface guess right?

This problem is origin from picture below which is from Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces.



Think of the ricci flow on the round sphere. How come it has $\int R d\mu = 0$?

@ArcticChar  It is the (normalized) ricci flow on compact surface (not only sphere). In this section, the author consider the case $r=\frac{\int R d\mu}{\int d\mu}=0$ (in fact, $r$ is a constant). He prove the scalar curvature will convergence to zero  in this case.

Then write down that it is not the ricci flow, but the normalized one. Also, from the Gauss bonnet you seem to be assuming that the surface is of genus one.

@ArcticChar  Yes, so it is. But seemly, the author don't care about the genus, he care about estimates. So I want to know how to estimate the $R$, since I always follow the author when I read paper.

@ArcticChar Hey, I find a way to deal it. I write it in problem.  Is it right?
